# Completion Handler

Tags: swift, swift3

When I create my method who calls a webservice, I pass a responseHandler.
Then at the end of this method I have:
responseHandler (false , nil , error , nil)

What does it mean ? Am I executing an another method passing (false, nil, error, nil ) OR I am returning this to the same method ?
What is done when this "responseHandler (false , nil , error , nil)" is executed ?

METHOD =====================================

```
func sessionTaskPostRequest (_ urlRequest : URLRequest , responseHandler: @escaping  ResponseHandler) -> URLSessionTask {
 let sesstionTask : URLSessionTask = networkSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data : Data? , urlResponse : URLResponse? , error : NSError? ) in

    var json: NSDictionary!
    do {
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? NSDictionary
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    if(error != nil) {
        responseHandler (false , nil , error , nil)
    }
```

THX

Comment: You are passing a function as the 'sessionTaskPostRequest' parameter (handler). Once the code is run, the response handler will run.

Answer (score 0):

responseHandler here is a block of code.

**What does it mean?**

In most cases you use a block of code to handle the response of an asynchronous event. So, in your case you're trying to know if your request to the server was a success or not.

**Suggestion**

I suggest you to search in your code where the type ResponseHandler is declared. I think it might be something like:

```
typealias ResponseHandler = (p1: Type, p2: Type, p3: Type, p4: Type) -> Void
```

so looking at the params real names you should be able to know what you pass to this block.

Another thing, I think you should call this block when you get a success too. Otherwise you are only reporting when the async function fails.